# adding icon beside woocomerce add to card button

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new on coding, so I'm using wordpress and woocomerce for my shop please check the image below, that's my plan. But can you please teach me the right way for it?

How can I put the image before the add to cart text?

[image: how can i put image before the add to cart text]

```
.prod_cart a.button.product_type_simple.add_to_cart_button.ajax_add_to_cart {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: transparent;
        background: url('../img/1.png') no-repeat;

}
```

Comment: Use an icon font. Nobody uses images for monochrome icons anymore these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `display:block` or `display:inline-block` and change background to `background:url('../img/1.png') no-repeat left 10px center transparent`

`left 10px` will position image 10px from left side of button. Also you should set some paddings to your button or set width and height.